# Guice load properties from System Properties

Tags: java, guice, governator

I am using Guice without any spring dependencies.

Is there way to get System properties passed to java (java -Dfoo="asda") in Module.
The goal is to load properties from outside of jar file.

Most examples so far use preexisting properties file

Similar to this question:
[Guice properties injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623295/guice-properties-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use [`Names.bindProperties()`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/name/Names.html#bindProperties(com.google.inject.Binder,java.util.Properties))

Usage is very easy:

```
@Override protected void configure() {
  Names.bindProperties(binder(), System.getProperties());
}
```

Then each time you inject `@Named("java.user.home") String` you'll get the value of `System.getProperty("java.user.home")`.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

used System.getProperty() as temprary solution. But hope there is more elegant way

Comment: More elegant in what way?

Comment: with annotation...In spring tehy use @Value

Comment: or PropertySource